# Filtering with multiple metafilters in JBehave

Tags: java, selenium, filtering, jbehave

**Situation:**

In my current project we are running all kinds of different JBehave stories. Every ".story" file is related to a product and a flow.

**Example:**
xyz-cellphone-call.story would be the story describing making a phonecall with a cellphone.
xyz-phone-call.story would be the story describing making a phonecall with a fixed-line phone.
xyz-cellphone-browse.story would be the story describing browsing the internet with a cellphone.

**My question:**
In Jbehave you can add metaFilters to filter on the stories based on meta tags. Assume the tags are @product & @action. (@product cellphone, @action call).
Would it be possible to pass a filter to run the JBehave stories concerning both the phone & cellphone stories, if yes, what would be the syntax?

I've tried adding the following filters (none of which work):

```
+product cellphone +product phone
+product cellphone|phone
+product cellphone,phone
```

Same for actions.

Is it possible to filter on multiple meta-tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.
In the API docs you will find this information:

> A filter is uniquely identified by its String representation which is
>   parsed and matched by the MetaFilter.MetaMatcher to determine if the
>   Meta is allowed or not.
>
> The MetaFilter.DefaultMetaMatcher interprets the filter as a sequence
>   of any name-value properties (separated by a space), prefixed by "+"
>   for inclusion and "-" for exclusion. E.g.:
>
> MetaFilter filter = new MetaFilter("+author Mauro -theme smoke testing
>   +map *API -skip");  filter.allow(new Meta(asList("map someAPI")));
>
> The use of the MetaFilter.GroovyMetaMatcher is triggered by the prefix
>   "groovy:" and allows the filter to be interpreted as a Groovy
>   expression.
>
> MetaFilter filter = new MetaFilter("groovy: (a == '11' | a == '22')
>   && b == '33'");

So probably if you play with the conditions, you will get your run configuration customized. 
Try this example:

> mvn clean install -P -Djbehave.meta.filter="myCustomRunConf:(+product && +action)"

More info amout the MetaFilter class in the API docs:
http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/javadoc/core/org/jbehave/core/embedder/MetaFilter.html

Comment: Okay, I will have to retry this, but in the past I have tried the filter "+product phone +action call" and it did not work.

Comment: @HPacquee I updated the answer, I think now is more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is easier solution for you using groovy
http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/meta-filtering.html

In your case it would be 
-Dmetafilter="groovy: "product=='cellphone' && action=='call'"

I tried it as "-Dmetafilter=groovy:t2 && t3" for this feature file

```
Meta:
    @t1

Narrative:
    As a user
    I want to blah-blah-blah


Scenario: test 1
Meta:
    @t2

Given I am on home page


Scenario: test 2
Meta:
    @t2
    @t3

Given I am on home page


Scenario: test 3
Meta:
    @t3

Given I am on home page
```

Only test 2 scenario is executed in this case

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
mvn clean install -P -Djbehave.meta.filter = "+product cellphone&&phone"
```