# Cannot get JBehave metafilters to work from a mvn command line

Tags: java, maven, jbehave

I have a series of JBehave tests that I run from the command line via

```
mvn integration-test
```

I am trying to decorate a subset of tests with a meta tag `SpecialPurpose`, which only get run on-demand:

```
Meta:
@SpecialPurpose

Scenario: Run this test only from the nightly build
```

Following [Filtering with multiple metafilters in JBehave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11742151/filtering-with-multiple-metafilters-in-jbehave), I try the following command line:

```
mvn integration-test -Djbehave.meta.filter="myCustomRunConf:(+SpecialPurpose)"
```

This runs all the tests in the suite. For completeness, I also tried

```
mvn integration-test -Djbehave.meta.filter="+SpecialPurpose"
```

and

```
mvn integration-test -Dmeta.filter="+SpecialPurpose"
```

as described at https://kowalcj0.wordpress.com/2013/01/22/how-to-selectively-run-in-jbehave-stories-tagged-with-multiple-words-in-a-meta-field/. None of these appear to successfully filter.

And for completeness, the pom.xml segment related to JBehave is

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>serenity-reports</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>aggregate</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>integration-test</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <includes>
            <include>**/integration/*.java</include>
            <include>**/integration/component1/*.java</include>
            <include>**/integration/component2/*.java</include>
            <include>**/integration/component3/*.java</include>
          </includes>
          <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
          <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

1) What is the proper syntax for decorating a story for inclusion?

2) What is the proper command-line?

3) Is there something unusual with the pom.xml definition that is intercepting or breaking the metafilter?

Comment: Correct parameter appears to be -Dmeta.filter, according to example in https://github.com/jbehave/jbehave-tutorial/blob/master/etsy-selenium/groovy-pico/pom.xml

Answer (score 1):

To handle the real features of Jbehave, use jbehave-maven-plugin in maven. To run the test configure maven jbehave plugin as below.

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
<artifactId>jbehave-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>4.0</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>run-stories-as-embeddables</id>
        <phase>test</phase>
        <configuration>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <testSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java/</testSourceDirectory>
            <testClassesDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/</testClassesDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/integration/*.java</include>
                <include>**/integration/component1/*.java</include>
                <include>**/integration/component2/*.java</include>
                <include>**/integration/component3/*.java</include>
            </includes>
            <threads>1</threads>
            <metaFilters>
                <metaFilter>${meta.filter}</metaFilter>
            </metaFilters>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
            <goal>integration-test</goal>
            <goal>run-stories-as-embeddables</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
<dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>log4j</groupId>
         <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
         <version>1.2.17</version>
         <scope>compile</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

In the run time use

```
mvn integration-test -Dmeta.filter="+SpecialPurpose"
```